# What is the significance of the exclamation mark (!) on ACARS page of a Boeing 737?

Tags: boeing-737, acars

For a while now I've noticed an exclamation mark on the ACARS inflight page of the B737NG at the beginning of a flight. It is located in the top left corner of the page and it just disappears after a while. I've been searching high and low what it means but can't find it.
Any ideas?

[image: ACARS page with !]

Comment: I presume this is on a flight sim?

Comment: No, it's on a real plane

Comment: Not sure what options Boeing offers on the 737NG, but I assume this is a Honeywell product?

Comment: Yes, it's a Honeywell. FMC is 10.8 but I don't know if there is a specific acars/datalink version.

Comment: The ACARS menus can be customized by the airline/operator. They have a PC based configuration tool that can be used to add and modify menu items and messages. Perhaps this is specific to your company.

Comment: Ah, Thanks. I'll put out the request there!

Comment: If it is company specific, and if you're allowed, please be sure to come back to tell us what it means. Feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: If it's company specific make sure they don't mind you posting it first.

Comment: @GdD, that was the `and if you're allowed` part... ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay guys, the verdict is in.

It is a symbol to indicate the crew alerting chimes are inhibited.
From OUT (off block) until OFF+15 and estimated ON-10 until IN (on block) the chimes to alert for new data and messages are suppressed to avoid nuisance warnings during critical flight phases.

Happy landings!

Comment: On other FMC configurations, the chime is only inhibited below some flight level, e.g. FL230.